# How A DataGridView.Datasource is stored in DataTable Variable

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable, datasource

I have to store datasource of datagridview in any Datatable variable for merge the data in gridview

```
Datatable dt = dataGridView1.DataSource;
```

and please also tell me how can I merge a data of same datagridview

Comment: What do you mean by merge?

Comment: You can call it anywhere why store it?

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to cast DataSource object to DataTable.

```
Datatable dt = myGridView.DataSource as DataTable;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you set your `DataSource` to a `DataTable` then you need a simple cast:

```
DataTable dt = (DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource;
```

If you want to merge two DataTables then you can use [DataTable.Merge](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.merge%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
dt1.Merge(dt2)
```